# Morphing of Equipotentials of a point charge in a grounded box

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, mathematics

If we place a point charge in a grounded metal box and view a slice of the box, the lines of equipotential deform from circular (immediately around the point charge, as we'd expect) to square at around the perimeter of the box where it is grounded.

Is there a mathematical relationship we can derive for the morphing of the field lines from circular to square? I am unsure if the change is a linear combination of the two functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the potential in this case. You typically have two main methods. Either you expand into basis functions by separation of variables. The basis functions will be of the form:
$$
e_n=\sin(\pi n_x x/L_x)\sin(\pi n_y y/L_y)\sin(\pi n_z z/L_z)
$$
assuming your box is $(0,L_x)\times(0,L_y)\times(0,L_z)$ in cartesian coordinates.

Alternatively, you can use the method of images by reflecting the charge by the faces of the box. Both approaches are equivalent by the Poisson summation formula.

In any case, you can calculate the potential and thus track how the level surfaces morph from a sphere to a parallelepiped.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Any further resources to understand the first method, it isn't covered in my electromagnetism notes. Unsure how you set up the equation which you seperate variables for

Comment: You solve for Laplace’s equation with Dirichlet boundary conditions. This follows from Gauss’ law. This is covered in Griffiths section 3.3 and Jackson chapter 3.

Comment: Is there any intuition for this? I now have shown how the potential deforms but is there a satisfying explanation for why the field and equipotentials reach this state?

Comment: Depends on what you are looking for. By calculating the field asymptotically, you know that the equipotential $V=0$ is a parallelepiped since it’s prescribed by the Dirichlet conditions. On the other hand, around the charge, you essentially have a Coulomb potential, so the equipotential lines are circular. I don’t think that there is an intuitive way to describe the morphing, you’ll need to do the math.